# Why can a derived class virtual function call a base class virtual function? How compiler implement?

Tags: c++

```
virtual void dev_class::v_func1()
{
    base_class::v_func1();
    cout << "This is dev_class's v_func1()" << endl;
}
```

In `dev_class`'s v-table, `base_class::v_func1()` has already overrided by  `dev_class::v_func1()`. Then, why `dev_class::v_func1()` can call `base_class::v_func1()`? Where is the `base_class::v_func1()` function address storing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use *qualified function name* in a call, the specified function is called directly, without using any "v-tables". That applies to calls of base class member function from derived class member function (as in your example). That applies to member function calls in all other contexts as well.

For example

```
base_class *p = new dev_class;
p->v_func1(); // virtual call - calls `dev_class::v_func1`
p->base_class::v_func1(); // non-virtual call - calls `base_class::v_func1`
```

Qualified function names suppress and override virtual dispatch mechanism and effectively turn virtual member function call into an ordinary member function call.

Answer (score 2):

`base_class::v_func1()` is called without using the v-table, just like any non-virtual function.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler simply knows addresses of all virtual tables of all classes. This is the same to ask "how compiler sets VMT in the constructor"? Addresses of the functions that are stored in VMTs are simply functions and they are known to compiler in pretty much the same way.